# What does this little 'A' denote in the project navigator for a playground?

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I'm using the Playground to debug some Swift code, using the techniques discussed in the official Swift blog at https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=26

I've noticed a small 'A' next to the source code file for the code I'm working on. Can somebody tell me what this means?

[image: A]

Comment: Subversion ...once you commit it will go away I guess

Comment: 'A' Denotes Added...'M' denotes modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Version Control(Subversion or Git)

It means you have added a new file that is what A signifies.

Once you commit it will go away.

Comment: Today it's most likely Git, not subversion. More precisely a versioning system.